# Running two different threads concurrently in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm fairly new to threading in android but I have a question.

**Prerequisite:**
The project is like an Uber app.
I have a popup modal that requests for a driver. If within one minute no driver is available the modal should close and notify the user that no driver was found. If response was received within the one minute, modal should also hide but show a different view.

I have 2 different threads that I need to run concurrently. I have tried to put all the functionalities I need to do in one thread but it doesn't seem to work out.

The first thread loops while checking if a driver was found. The second thread hides the modal from showing and if no driver is not received it should terminate the first thread.

**Problem**
The first thread runs concurrently with the second but does not hide the modal nor does it show a different view in the event that a driver is available.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

*Kindly ignore the logs, I was trying to understand the logic of flow within the threads*

```
private void showRequestPopUp(View view){
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    locationLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    requestLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    driverLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    geoLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View requestRidePopUp = Objects.requireNonNull(layoutInflater).inflate(R.layout.modal_request_ride, null);

    boolean focusable = true;
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(requestRidePopUp, width, height, focusable);
    popupWindow.setElevation(8);

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    requestRidePopUp.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            popupWindow.isShowing();
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Thread Initialization
    Thread loadingThread;
    final Thread exitThread;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    exitThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();

            // Update the progress bar
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Running Exit Thread");

                        while(STOP_THREAD) {
                            if (DR_NAME != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "STOP THREAD: ");
                                showDriverDetails();
                                popupWindow.dismiss();
                            }

                            Thread.interrupted();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Thread Status: " + Thread.interrupted());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // Dismiss Loading Window After 1 Minute
    loadingThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(TAG, "Running Loading Thread");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!interrupted()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Hide Loading Screen");

                        if (DR_NAME == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "We could not find any driver near you. Try again Later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            popupWindow.dismiss();

                            locationLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            requestLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            driverLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            geoLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
                                    geoLocation.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 590);
                            geoLocation.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                            // End Exit Thread
                            STOP_THREAD = true;

                            Thread.interrupted();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Interrupted Loading Thread: " + Thread.interrupted());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    loadingThread.start();
    exitThread.start();

    // Request Ride
    requestRideNotification();

    Button cancelRide = requestRidePopUp.findViewById(R.id.cancelRequest);
    cancelRide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();

            locationLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            requestLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            driverLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            geoLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
                    geoLocation.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 590);
            geoLocation.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Make sure your variable `STOP_THREAD` is declared to be `volatile` or use an `AtomicBoolean` instead. Otherwise the JVM may simply copy the value and use one copy for each thread. Which of course causes problem in case you change the variable in one thread which might not get propagated to the second thread if the value has been copied by the JVM internally.

Comment: Declaring `STOP_THREAD` variable to be `volatile` doesn't help me achieve my solution. The loading screen is still showing yet the `STOP_THREAD` value is `true`.

Comment: @KithBlack what if you set STOP_THREAD outside of the if clause. It looks like your code only sets STOP_THREAD to true  and dismisses the popup window if the driver name is null.

Comment: @zacmwa The `STOP_THREAD` value is set to `false` initially and outside of this context. When a driver is found `STOP_THREAD` is set to `true` - this is also set outside of this context - and with that `DR_NAME` is populate with a value and this dismisses the `popupWindow`. 

If no driver was found after 60 sec, the second thread (`loadingThread`) sets the `STOP_THREAD` value to `true` and since the `DR_NAME` is null the first thread (`exitThread`) is stopped. 

This is the expected flow of the process but it seems to be failing with `exitThread`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from a friend and all I had to do was re-organize the flow of information inside the first thread and walla!

```
private void showRequestPopUp(View view){
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    locationLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    requestLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    driverLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    geoLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View requestRidePopUp = Objects.requireNonNull(layoutInflater).inflate(R.layout.modal_request_ride, null);

    boolean focusable = true;
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(requestRidePopUp, width, height, focusable);
    popupWindow.setElevation(8);

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    requestRidePopUp.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            popupWindow.isShowing();
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Thread Initialization
    Thread loadingThread;
    final Thread responseThread;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    responseThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            int count = 0;

            while(!STOP_THREAD) {
                count ++;
            }

            if (DR_NAME != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Running Response Thread");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Response Thread DR_NAME: " + DR_NAME);
                            showDriverDetails();
                            popupWindow.dismiss();

                            Log.e(TAG, "Stop Thread: " + STOP_THREAD);
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Interrupt Response Thread: " + Thread.interrupted());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    // Dismiss Loading Window After 1 Minute
    loadingThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(TAG, "Running Loading Thread");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!interrupted()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Active Loading Thread");

                        if (DR_NAME == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "We could not find any driver near you. Try again Later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            popupWindow.dismiss();

                            locationLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            requestLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            driverLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            geoLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
                                    geoLocation.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 590);
                            geoLocation.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                            // End Exit Thread
                            STOP_THREAD = true;
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Interrupt Loading Thread: " + Thread.interrupted());
                        } else {
                            // End Exit Thread
                            STOP_THREAD = false;
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Interrupt Loading Thread: " + Thread.interrupted());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    loadingThread.start();
    responseThread.start();

    // Request Ride
    requestRideNotification();

    Button cancelRide = requestRidePopUp.findViewById(R.id.cancelRequest);
    cancelRide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();

            locationLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            requestLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            driverLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            geoLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
                    geoLocation.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 590);
            geoLocation.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
}
```